# Trigger a action upon success full response of another action ngrx

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

I created a ngrx `effect` that's responsible for sending a POST request to a back end. now i want to change the implementation little bit. if the post request is successful I want to trigger another action that responsible update my ngrx store. but I couldn't figure out how to do that.

I tried to use switch map and merge map but didn't work.

```
creatTour$ = createEffect(() =>
   this.actions$.pipe(
       ofType(TourAction.createTour),
        mergeMap((action) => {
            const payload = action.tour;
            const endpoint = environment.urls.tour.replace("{tourProviderId}", "1");
             const request = new ServiceRequest(endpoint, 'POST', payload, options);

             return this.requestHandlerService.invoke(request).pipe(
                map((sucessResponce) => {
                   if (sucessResponce.code === 200) {
                        TourListAction.updateTourList({ tour: [tour] }) // i want to trigger this action and
                                                                            // below action 
                     }
                   return TourAction.createTourSucess({ responce: sucessResponce.message })
                    }),
                    catchError(err => {
                        const errorMessage = JSON.stringify(err);
                        console.log(errorMessage);
                        return of(TourAction.createTourFail({ errorMessage }))
                    })
                )
            })
        )
    );
```

i tried this way too

```
return [TourAction.createTourSucess({ responce: sucessResponce.message }
        TourListAction.updateTourList({ tour: [tour] })]
```

it throws this error

```
 Property 'type' is missing in type '(({ responce: string; } 
 & TypedAction<"[Tour] Create Tour Success">) | ({ tour: Tours[]; } & 
 TypedAction<"[Tour List] Tour List Update">))[]' but required in type 
 'Action'.
```

is this the better way to do this.i saw there is new thing called `entity` should I use that for this implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not update your state on the `createTourSucess` action?

You can also return multiple actions:

```
.pipe(
  switchMap(() => 
    return [
    TourListAction.updateTourList({ tour: [tour] }) ,  
    TourAction.createTourSucess({ responce: sucessResponce.message })
    ]
  )
)
```

https://medium.com/@amcdnl/dispatching-multiple-actions-from-ngrx-effects-c1447ceb6b22

Comment: I referred to this article before but I couldn't understand where do I need to change.also it throws error like this `Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action> | ((...args: any[]) => Observable<Action>)'.
  Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action>'.
    Property 'type' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Action'.`

Comment: Change your inner `map` to `switchMap`

Answer (score 1):

You can return multiple actions from your effect, they will all be dispatched.

See https://medium.com/@tanya/understanding-ngrx-effects-and-the-action-stream-1a74996a0c1c
For your code:

```
return successResponse.code === 200 ? [
    createTourUpdateAction(tour), 
    TourAction.createTourSuccess
    ] : [TourAction.createTourSuccess]
```

Comment: I tried to use this method but it throws a compile error which I can't post here as a comment because of the length. I tried so many ways but nothing works.